# Linear Regression with explicit intercept in R -- using lmodel2 for major axis regression

Tags: r, regression, intercept

I want to calculate a linear regression using the `lmodel2()` function in R using the "MA" (major axis) method (using the `lmodel2` package). Additionally, I want to get the slope of a regression, where I explicitly give the intercept to `lmodel2()` as 0.  (Since the data cannot take negative values, I know a priori that the intercept should be 0). With the function `lm()`, the following syntax works by adding **0 +**:

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
plot (lin$x, lin$y)
fit <- lm(lin$y ~ 0 + lin$x)
summary(fit)
```

If I try using the same method (adding **0 +**) with the function lmodel2, it doesn't work.  Both give the same results and estimate a non-zero intercept.

```
library(lmodel2)
fit_1 <- lmodel2(lin$y ~ lin$x)
fit_2 <- lmodel2(lin$y ~ 0 + lin$x)
```

Also, if it is possible, it would be valuable to know how to plot the result using `abline()`.

(Note this post uses sample code from the post "Linear Regression with explicit intercept in R", which explains how to suppress intercept using ordinary least squares regression with `lm()` )

Comment: -1 might work instead of 0. Also, it would be good to point out that you are using a third-party R package, lmodel2.

Comment: -1 doesn't work :(   (I've added the package name to the post/question)